# How to fix qml TextField misbehaving on android?

Tags: android, qt, qml

In summary in `qml` if you have a `TextField` component inside a `Page` (on android) and you start to type something in it and then press on it again and continue typing the orginal text gets duplicated.
For example I pressed on the `Textfield` and typed:

> sb

then i pressed on it again (without pressing enter or confirm button) and typed

> g

the text becomes

> sbsbg

instead of "sbg"

The code:

```
Window {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  Page{
    anchors.fill: parent
    TextField{
        id: textField
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing this problem - I am also having it. I found going from 5.12.3 back to 5.12.0 fixes it for now.